# How can I group an array of objects by a unique code?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects (**example**):

```
[
  {
     'Row Labels': '37383783738',
     'ProdCode&Desc': '8H9H89 Homestyle cinnamon cake (200g) 8x120',
  },      
  {
     'Row Labels': '37383783738',
     'ProdCode&Desc': '9HD063 Goodness me! Chargrilled bites (20g) 6x30',
  },      
  {
     'Row Labels': '83322223733',
     'ProdCode&Desc': '39HSH02 MDS Chargrilled Hot & Spicy (40g) 2x30',
  },
  {
     'Row Labels': '83322223733',
     'ProdCode&Desc': '93JSHS Treasured battered fillet (120g) 6x30',
  },
]
```

How can I loop through each element in array and if the current element's 'Row Label' code matches the next elements 'Row Label' code - then add that ProdCode&Desc to the end of the current elements ProdCode&Desc, with each string being separated by a semi colon.

The expected output of the **example** above would be:

```
[
  {
     'Row Labels': '37383783738',
     'ProdCode&Desc': '8H9H89 Homestyle cinnamon cake (200g)8x120; 9HD063 Goodness me! Chargrilled bites (20g) 6x30',
  },           
  {
     'Row Labels': '83322223733',
     'ProdCode&Desc': '39HSH02 MDS Chargrilled Hot & Spicy (40g) 2x30; 93JSHS Treasured battered fillet (120g) 6x30',
  },
]
```

This is what i have so far:

```
records.map((record, index, array) => {
   if (record["Row Labels"]
   .toLowerCase()
   .includes(array[index + 1]["Row Lables"].toLowerCase())
) {
   record.push(array[index + 1]["ProdCode&Desc"]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using array [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
const data = [
  {
    'Row Labels': '37383783738',
    'ProdCode&Desc': '8H9H89 Homestyle cinnamon cake (200g) 8x120',
  },
  {
    'Row Labels': '37383783738',
    'ProdCode&Desc': '9HD063 Goodness me! Chargrilled bites (20g) 6x30',
  },
  {
    'Row Labels': '83322223733',
    'ProdCode&Desc': '39HSH02 MDS Chargrilled Hot & Spicy (40g) 2x30',
  },
  {
    'Row Labels': '83322223733',
    'ProdCode&Desc': '93JSHS Treasured battered fillet (120g) 6x30',
  },
];

const ret = Object.values(
  data.reduce((prev, c) => {
    const p = prev;
    const key = c['Row Labels'];
    if (!p[key]) p[key] = { ...c };
    else
      p[key] = {
        ...p[key],
        'ProdCode&Desc': (p[key]['ProdCode&Desc'] += `; ${c['ProdCode&Desc']}`),
      };
    return p;
  }, {})
);
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you mr hr. I really should take the time to learn .reduce and it's full capabilities.

Comment: Is there anyway to return the data in the exact way I stated in my expected output example?

Comment: @Perry, Sorry my mistake. I have updated the code. Now check it.